# modx revo do not print it alt = ""?

Tags: modx-revolution

Tell me how to do it, if there is no picture, then do not print it alt = ""? And if there is something to show?
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQoop.png)

Comment: <img src="[[+tv.image_main:phpthumbof=`w=360&h=240&zc=1`]]" class="img-responsive" alt="[[+pagetitle]]">

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the Stack Overflow [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no image it seems weird to output an `img` tag with ugly broken image icon even if you get rid of the `alt` attribute. There is a need for a fallback image or just don't show anything. So, try this in your template chunk:

```
[[+tv.image_main:notempty=`<img src="[[+tv.image_main:phpthumbof=`w=360&h=240&zc=1`]]" class="img-responsive" alt="[[+pagetitle]]">`]]
```

If your tv `image_main` exists, the image tag will be shown with tv's value in its `src` attribute. In the opposite case nothing will be shown.